# Run command if exists

Tags: shell, unix

I need a simple way to run the code below only if the command / file exists on the server.

```
/etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond stop
```

Ideally it's something simple that goes before the command.

```
check /etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond && /etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
[ -x /etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond ] && /etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond stop
```

`-x /etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond` checkes if the given file exists and is executable (or search) permission is granted.